# Trouble using cd command with "~" or "$HOME" in bash scripting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, home-directory

We know that `~` and `$HOME` refer to the home directory of the current user. (For me `echo ~`=`echo $HOME`=`pandya`).

But I can't use it in bash scripting.  Here is a simple example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter Directory Path:"
read dir1
cd $dir1
```

But When executed, it gives error **`No such file or directory`** as follows:

```
$ ./script
Enter Directory Path:~/Desktop
./script: line 4: cd: ~/Desktop: No such file or directory
```

If `/home/pandya` used instead of `~` ,then it is working.

Same problem with `$HOME`.

Thus, How to properly use `cd` with `~` or `$HOME` in such bash scripting?

Comment: Hint: if input starts with "~" replace "~" with "/home/$HOME".

Comment: @Pandya now try my answer !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using **eval** command :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter Directory Path:"
read dir1
eval cd "$dir1"
```

Because in your code `$dir1` will not store `~/Desktop` but it will store `/home/user/Desktop` so you can use eval command .

To understand **Eval** command [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses)

Comment: I would love to see an explanation of what the `eval` command means and does.

Comment: @nux ok. `eval` is helpful to use.

Comment: Just don't try entering `; rm -rf /` as the path.

Comment: One thing about eval, as @choroba alluded to - eval is very dangerous. If you're using this for your own private use, don't worry about it. If you're giving this to someone else to use you should either warn them to be careful with it OR (and this is the better option) put in some sort of checking to make sure that they entered a directory and not something else, like `; rm -rf /`

Comment: "in your code $dir1 will not store ~/Desktop" yes it will - that's the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example which works.

As said before, the expansion of variables from input is the key.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Dir:"
read dir1
dir2=`eval echo $dir1`
cd $dir2
pwd
```

Of course, you should not expect that your current shell will change its working directory after script execution. It will remain unaffected.

Comment: @Pandya Yes it _is_ changing the working directory. But not in the calling shell environment. Why would you want to have a script which does what `cd` does?

Comment: Yes it is working but more simple with @nux answer!

Comment: @Pandya You know as well as I do that my comment referred to an earlier comment of yours, which you deleted in the meantime, in which you claimed that my solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the tilde expansion happens before variable expansion (see `man bash` for details). Variable expansion happens just once, so `$dir1` is expanded, but the string `$HOME` inside it is not.

It might be easier to specify the directory path as a command line argument instead of using `read` to read it from the console: the shell will expand it for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir1=$1
cd "$dir1"
pwd
```

and call it like

```
./script ~/Desktop
```

Another alternative is to use a file dialog instead of typing the path at all:

```
dialog --dselect / 20 20
```

Comment: @Pandya: Fixed a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use of eval has security issues.
Just substitute tilde with variable HOME instead.

```
# Expand Tilde.
d="~/somedir";
d="${d/#\~/${HOME}}";
```